# Which is more efficient, searching on string vs bytearrays?

Tags: java, arrays, string, performance, byte

We have a use case where we wanted to decide on using string vs byte[].
Using string brings us a penalty of encoding and decoding multiple times at various layers of our application, which byte[] avoids by its nature (Is this assumption even correct?). And we may have to do some "concatenations" and "contains/indexOf" operations on this data structure (string/byte[]). I am trying to understand how searching on string is different than searching on raw bytes. If so, we can safely go with byte[] without undergoing any penalty of encoding.

Which is efficient Searching on string or its equivalent raw bytes?

Is it an apple to apple comparison?

Comment: Do you work with text in a human language, or do you work with sequences of small numbers?

Comment: This is partly a question of requirements. Do you need to support characters outside Latin-1? Then using String or char[] will be simpler than byte[].

Comment: @Joni are you saying working on raw bytes is slower and strings usually deal with such operations better ?

Comment: The answer is "it depends"

Comment: @AndyThomas yes, it can take any international characters. When you say simpler, do you meant easy to work with or strings are more performant?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel can you name some factors on which it depends

Comment: Go with `Byte array` instead of `String` because strings are immutable and consists of 16-bit char in `Java`. On the other hand byte array are easily recycled, have good cache locality ,can be saved directly (No heap usage), avoids character encoders. This all assumes you are using ASCII data. Also if f you have to parse a lot of string data its better to use a byte array than a string .

Comment: @Amitkumar byte arrays are allocated on the heap, so I'm not sure what you mean with "no heap usage".

Comment: This is not a question of speed. This is a question of what you need. Human language is complicated and you need special tools to work with it, especially if you work in an international setting where different languages can mix with business concerns. If you work with other kinds of data (image/video/audio files, DNA sequences, machine learning models, ...) you need to use different tools.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 9 the `String` class internally uses a `byte[]`, so it will use one byte per character. If you only deal with ASCII chars, it will use one byte per character, so you will not save any memory by using `byte[]` yourself, if that's your concern.

If you have non ASCII chars with two or even more bytes, you cannot assume that one character takes one byte.

You would have to take care of the encoding and decoding yourself, and the `String` class in Java is already very optimized in that.

In short, I would recommend using `String`, unless you can really prove a performance gain in using `byte[]` over `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Processing byte arrays is more efficient than processing character strings, because characters are 16bit in Java. However, if you need features related to character processing, then byte arrays are not suitable (except if you restrict your application to 7bit US-ASCII, which I would not recommend).